# Registering a AURenderCallback in Swift

Tags: swift, core-audio, swift2

I am trying to build a Metronome for iOS in Swift. I am using NSTimers to trigger each click, but this is too unprecise. In various Forums people say, that i should register AURencerCallback.

Right now I have the following Code:

```
init()
{
    let audioUnit:AudioUnit
    AudioUnitInitialize(audioUnit)
    AudioUnitAddRenderNotify(audioUnit, renderTone, self);
}
```

My Callback-Function:

```
func callback(
    inRefCon:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>,
    ioActionFlags:UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,
    inTimeStamp:UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
    inBusNumber:UInt32,
    inNumberFrames:UInt32,
    ioData:UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>) -> (OSStatus)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Could someone please show what I need to do, or show me examples of working code?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late perhaps, but have a look at my answer in this thread:

[AURenderCallback in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33715628/aurendercallback-in-swift)

Hope that helps you too.