# AURenderCallback in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, audiounit

I am creating an application that uses Audio Units, and while there are many examples of code in Objective-C (including Apple's own aurioTouch and others) I am attempting to code the entire thing in Swift.

I have been able to set up my AUGraph and run some audio through it, but I cannot seem to figure out the syntax for the render callbacks. I have tried a couple of methods:

**Method 1: Create an AURenderCallback directly**

```
let render : AURenderCallback = { (
    inRefCon: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>,
    ioActionFlags: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,
    inTimeStamp: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
    inBufNumber: UInt32,
    inNumberFrames: UInt32,
    ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>) -> OSStatus in

    return noErr
}
```

I do nothing in this callback besides returning noErr at this point since I am just trying to make it work. However, the compiler returns the following error:

> (UnsafeMutablePointer,
>   UnsafeMutablePointer,
>   UnsafePointer, UInt32, UInt32,
>   UnsafeMutablePointer) -> OSStatus' is not convertible
>   to 'AURenderCallback

The definition of AURenderCallback in the documentation is this:

```
typealias AURenderCallback = (UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>,UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>, UInt32, UInt32,UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>) -> OSStatus
```

It seems to be the same as what I had entered, although it could be that I do not understand what the documentation is asking for.

**Method 2: Create a function representing the AURenderCallback**

```
func render(
    inRefCon: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>,
    ioActionFlags: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,
    inTimeStamp: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
    inBufNumber: UInt32,
    inNumberFrames: UInt32,
    ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>) -> OSStatus {

    return noErr
}
```

This does not give any errors as a function, but when I place it into AURenderCallbackStruct in the inputProc parameter I receive an error:

> Cannot find an initializer for type 'AURenderCallbackStruct' that
>   accepts an argument list of type '(inputProc:
>   (UnsafeMutablePointer,
>   UnsafeMutablePointer,
>   UnsafePointer, UInt32, UInt32,
>   UnsafeMutablePointer) -> OSStatus, inputProcRefCon:
>   nil)

I have not found many examples of creating AURenderCallbacks in Swift, and there seems to be a large difference in syntax compared with Objective-C. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just found your post while trying to figure out the same (it's not easy finding sample code and examples combining CoreAudio/Audio Unit and Swift).

By looking at [this repository](https://github.com/ooper-shlab/aurioTouch2.0-Swift) and reading (several times :-)) Apples documentation about [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html) I managed to piece something together. As it says in the section about `Function Pointers`

> When calling a function that takes a function pointer argument, you can pass a top-level Swift function, a closure literal, or nil.

So. Outside of my class I have a method that looks like this:

```
func renderCallback(inRefCon:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>,
ioActionFlags:UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,
inTimeStamp:UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
inBusNumber:UInt32,
inNumberFrames:UInt32,
ioData:UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>) -> OSStatus {
    let delegate = unsafeBitCast(inRefCon, AURenderCallbackDelegate.self)
    let result = delegate.performRender(ioActionFlags,
        inTimeStamp: inTimeStamp,
        inBusNumber: inBusNumber,
        inNumberFrames: inNumberFrames,
        ioData: ioData)
    return result
}
```

As you can see, I just call a delegate here. That delegate is declared like so (also outside the class but you already knew that :-))

```
@objc protocol AURenderCallbackDelegate {
func performRender(ioActionFlags: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,
    inTimeStamp: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
    inBusNumber: UInt32,
    inNumberFrames: UInt32,
    ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>) -> OSStatus
}
```

Doing so enables me to "get back inside my class" by conforming to the `AURenderCallbackDelegate` like so:

`class AudioUnitGraphManager: NSObject, AURenderCallbackDelegate`

And then implementing the `renderCallback` method in my `AudioUnitGraphManager` class

```
func performRender(ioActionFlags: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>, inTimeStamp: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>, inBusNumber: UInt32, inNumberFrames: UInt32, ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>) -> OSStatus {
    print("Hello there!")
    return noErr
}
```

The final piece of the puzzle is to actually enable the render notify callback which I do like so:

`AudioUnitAddRenderNotify(mixerUnit, renderCallback, UnsafeMutablePointer(unsafeAddressOf(self)))`

Hopefully this gives you something to continue the struggle with.

### Changes in Swift 3

In Swift 3 the declaration for `AURenderCallback` has changed to this:

`typealias AURenderCallback = (UnsafeMutableRawPointer, UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>, UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>, UInt32, UInt32, UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>?) -> OSStatus`

Notice the last parameter is now `UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>?` compared to `UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>` before (it is an optional now).

This means that the code now looks like this.

#### The `renderCallback` function

```
func renderCallback(inRefCon:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>,
ioActionFlags:UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,
inTimeStamp:UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
inBusNumber:UInt32,
inNumberFrames:UInt32,
ioData:UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>?) -> OSStatus {
    let delegate = unsafeBitCast(inRefCon, AURenderCallbackDelegate.self)
    let result = delegate.performRender(ioActionFlags,
        inTimeStamp: inTimeStamp,
        inBusNumber: inBusNumber,
        inNumberFrames: inNumberFrames,
        ioData: ioData)
    return result
}
```

#### The `AURenderCallbackDelegate` protocol

```
@objc protocol AURenderCallbackDelegate {
func performRender(ioActionFlags: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,
    inTimeStamp: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
    inBusNumber: UInt32,
    inNumberFrames: UInt32,
    ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>?) -> OSStatus
}
```

#### The actual implementation of `performRender`

```
    func performRender(ioActionFlags: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>, inTimeStamp: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>, inBusNumber: UInt32, inNumberFrames: UInt32, ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>?) -> OSStatus {
    print("Hello there!")
    return noErr
}
```

#### Enabling the render notify callback

```
AudioUnitAddRenderNotify(mixerUnit!, renderCallback, Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
```

Comment: The use of a delegate is an interesting approach. However I receive the following error when attempting to enable the callback:

'Cannot find an initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<T>' that accepts an argument list of type '(UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>).'

I have looked around for how to resolve this but I am pretty stumped. These pointer types are frustrating to say the least.

Comment: For the purposes of debugging, I attempted to create an AURenderCallbackStruct object so that I could define the parameters individually with dot syntax. This works fine: "renderCallbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = UnsafeMutablePointer(unsafeAddressOf(self))" but "renderCallbackStruct.inputProc = renderCallback" throws the now familiar compile error "Cannot assign a value of type '(UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>, UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>, UInt32, UInt32, UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>) -> OSStatus' to a value of type 'AURenderCallback'."

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. I tried to compile the project you linked above, and after I received a ton of errors I noticed that I was running XCode 6.4. I upgraded to version 7 and it works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked, and even more glad to see I'm not the only one spending hours on weird compiler messages caused by my own mistakes :-)

Comment: I'm struggling to get this to work. Could you post a complete source example?

Comment: Hi @PetrusTheron, oh wow, that was ages ago :) I made this for the company I worked at back then and the code is not public. However, I made this gist: https://gist.github.com/pbodsk/40bee78940385847b7e9780a70e2a937 which should contain...well...the gist (sorry!) of how this is set up and used. I removed some of the stuff from there but I hope it helps you just a little. Sorry, that is the best I can do.

Comment: Also @PetrusTheron, please note that AUGraph is being deprecated soonish, see this for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44952582/is-augraph-being-deprecated-on-ios-if-so-when just to say that maybe you should consider looking into the never `AVAudioEngine` if at all possible

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party but I found a way that might be more straightforward than the above answer. We can make use of the `inRefCon` pointer that you can set in the callbackStruct. `inRefCon` gets passed to your callback function, so if you set `inRefCon` to your class reference, you can directly "find your way back into the class" without needing to go loopdyloop with delegates. Here's how I did it:

```
/* below code is inside some function in MyClass */ 

var callbackStruct = AURenderCallbackStruct()

// set inRefCon to reference to self by casting to pointer
callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())

// create our C closure
callbackStruct.inputProc = {
             (inRefCon : UnsafeMutableRawPointer,
              ioActionFlags : UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,
              inTimeStamp : UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
              inBusNumber : UInt32,
              inNumberFrames : UInt32,
              ioData : UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>?) -> OSStatus in
            
            // get reference to my class by de-referencing inRefCon
            let _self = Unmanaged<MyClass>.fromOpaque(inRefCon).takeUnretainedValue()
            // time to profit with reference to our class _self
            // ...
            return 0
}

// set callback
AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit!,
                     kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                     kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                     0,
                     &callbackStruct,
                     UInt32(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: callbackStruct)))
```