# Is AUGraph being deprecated on iOS? If so, when?

Tags: ios, core-audio, deprecated, audiotoolbox, augraph

I've heard rumblings that `AUGraph` is being deprecated on iOS, for example in [this Twitter post](https://twitter.com/marcoarment/status/878323409339338753):

> @marcoarment Your comment on @atpfm about needing to rewrite your audio engine: b/c of the looming AUGraph deprecation, or something else?

Is `AUGraph` in fact being deprecated, and if so, when? Can somebody point me toward an official Apple document or announcement that clarifies this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed it will be deprecated as stated in the WWDC talk
[image]

(Note: The picture is from the core audio mailing list)